# Setting up mySQL db and TomCat on Windows for a website

Tags: mysql

I've been searching everywhere, and I just can't wrap my head around the procedure that lies in setting a server up with some schemas to be used along a website.

I'm using workbench, but also the command line way.

I have two desktop computers. One that I want for normal use. And the second to be put up as a mySQL database, and just that. The need here is that the database PC, should allow some kind of remote access, so that my website may connect to it.

Comment: I got a big fat 1000 pages about JDBC and database algorithm and stuff, had it in a 7 week course in my university. But this kind of "practical" stuff as actually useage, is never mentioned. Thought that meant it would be very simple.

Comment: I got a desktop PC with windows on, which I'd like to use for it, with MySQL DB

Comment: It says PHP, would it work for servlets aswell?

Comment: yes, sorry could've mentioned that.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks alot, appreciated!

Comment: you might want to use XAMPP, it comes with tomcat and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing MySQL Server in windows is easy, however first access have a small tricks. Start by downloading MySQL Server from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

During the install don't forget to check the options to add MySQL to the System Path Variables.

After that you'll have to reset the root password. For some weird reason the root password doesn't work (at least on windows). Follow the instructions here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

To make it shorter:

```
1) Type services.msc in start menu to open the service lists
2) Stop MySQL server
3) Create a txt file with the content below, placing the commands in 2 lines.
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
4) Execute this command on a DOS prompt
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\arquivo.txt --console
The init-file must point to the file created in item (3)
5) Delete the file created, restart MySQL service and logon normally with root user
```

To test your login, use a DOS prompt and type

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pMyNewPass (no spaces between "P" and your password).
```

Comment: I think I've been through this as I'm able to connect to my database. I open mysql.exe from my windows cmd, login sucessfully and can insert and tables etc. I also changed the root password through mysql workbench.

Comment: OK, so your problem seems more related with Tomcat or connecting through your software than actually getting the MySQL DB up and running. Is that it? Please update your Title and question in order to make it more clear for others who search for it in the future.

Comment: I were unsudden on how to clarify my question properly, but will try to do so now. I can connect to my database through eclipse/JDBC/tomcat, and everything works fine with insert and get etc. But I'm trying to setup another PC at my home, which is meant to be the database, so my website can connect to it.

Comment: Ah, OK! Connect inside your LAN only? On your server type "ifconfig" in a DOS prompt and look for IPv4 address inside the Ethernet Adapter section. That will be your server IP to connect. Port, user, password, etc, will remain the same. Also since it's a windows machine, don't forget to open port 3306 on the firewall. Otherwise windows will not allow you to connect.

Comment: Not just LAN(But I will toy with this abit to test), I want basically every client that uses my site, so that they my login and vice versa. I just stumpled across something- the hostname should be the domain of my site?

Comment: It's more complicaded if you want to access your local database from anywhere in the web. You'll have to portforward port 3306 in your modem and/or router to your DB server, and also find a way to make your WAN IP a fixed IP, since internet provides changes your IP from time to time. A good free solution is no-ip.org. It can be your domain, if your DNS resolves it to your WAN IP.